# Triggering a show/hide from existing jscript when specific tabs are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script in a php page that contains tabbed output

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#horizontalTab').ProductTabs({
        type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
        width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
        fit: true,   // 100% fit in a container
        closed: 'accordion', // Start closed if in accordion view
        activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
            var $tab = $(this);
            var $info = $('#tabInfo');
            var $name = $('span', $info);
            $name.text($tab.text());
            $info.show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If i put the following code in the html, it tells me the name of the tab that is currently open

```
<div id="tabInfo">
    Selected tab: <span class="tabName"></span>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can use whatever is giving the tab name to the span class to trigger a show or hide like

```
$('.pricefields td').hide();
```

JS is not my field at all, but looking at the initial script I'm guessing its related to var $info and var $name, but I don't have enough understanding to work out how to use those in a sort of if tabName == Tab1 then hide this td way.

I did try adding the following to the script, but the td still shows on all tabs. If I add the $('.pricefields td').hide(); without the if statement it hides, so I know the hide command is using the correct identifier.

```
if ($info === 'Product Information'){
$('.pricefields td').hide();
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Following the answer from smarx, I have updated the code, but am presented with another issue I hadn't considered.

The code is now as shown below (I have left the real world tab names in place):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#horizontalTab').ProductTabs({
type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion           
width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
fit: true,   // 100% fit in a container
closed: 'accordion', // Start closed if in accordion view
activate: function(event) { // Callback function if tab is switched
var $tab = $(this);
var $info = $('#tabInfo');
var $name = $('span', $info);
$name.text($tab.text());
$info.show();
if ($tab.text() === 'Product Information') {
$('.pricefields td').hide();
$('.productinfo td').show();
}
if ($tab.text() === 'Product Prices') {
$('.pricefields td').show();
$('.productinfo td').hide();
}
}
});
});
```

The problem I have now is that on page load, the pricefields td is still visible because the hide is not triggered unless the activate function event is triggered by someone clicking on the Product Information tab. Given that on first page load this is the open tab, they are not going to click it immediately.
I then decided that i could just add

```
$('.pricefields td').hide();
```

After the $(document).ready(function (), which does work, in a fashion. If the user refreshes the page whilst on another tab, the page then reloads on whatever tab they had open, but still hides the price fields. So if they happened to have been on the price tab, they see nothing.

I guess the solution is to have the currently active tab checked on page load, and have that trigger a first instance of .hide(), with subsequent triggers being handles by the original activate.

Would this make sense?

The html markup for the tabs is quite simple.

```
<div id="horizontalTab">
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li>Product Information</li>      
<li>Product Prices</li>
<li>Product Meta Data</li>  
</ul>

<div class="resp-tabs-container">
<div>
Product info tab content
</div>
<div>
Product price tab content
</div>
<div>
Product meta tab content
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your idea makes sense. If you need help figuring out which tab is active on page load, you'll have to share the HTML for the tabs.

Comment: Added to the original question

Comment: Ah, that doesn't actually help. :-) I guess the code for `ProductTabs` is what actually remembers the active tab and sets it on page load? Where's that code?

Comment: That would be the main js file, which is like the one here http://zencart.hosting/js/ProductTabs.js

Comment: To me, it looks like that code is already supposed to show and hide the content as appropriate. You shouldn't have to do any of this.

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/6mteuhkb/ and see if it does what you want. I think all I did was add CSS to visually show what the JavaScript library is already doing. (I made the active tab underlined and inactive tab content regions hidden.)

Comment: I will try and clarify this. The tabs code has been added to a php page called product, but the content of the tabs is generated by other php pages and called using require. The main issue is that product info and product prices are currently on the same page and they need to be separated into two different tabs. Given that you can't call the main page twice I decided to give classes to the content generated so that you could show/hide the required ones. with standard html use the tabs do work, in my use, they don't because I need it to be able to identify which tab is active at refresh.

Comment: Well, the active tab at page load is just the URL fragment, so `window.location.hash` should hopefully give you what you need. If not, I'd really suggest opening a new question and including the *full* HTML.

Comment: (More precisely, I think the hash is something like an element ID followed by a number, so you'll want to map that back to whichever tab is at that index.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tab.text()` is the thing that's showing up in the `tabName` span, so that's the "name" of the tab.

You could write code like this (inside the "activate" handler):

```
if ($tab.text() === 'Tab1') {
    $('.pricefields td').hide();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. One question though, $tab.text is empty until the activate handler has been triggered by a click. If I want to have $tab.text default to contain 'Tab1' as it always loads the page with this tab active, is there a simple solution? I did try adding var $tab = 'Tab1'; just after the $(document).ready(function () { but it made no difference.

Comment: Where do you want to use `$tab.text()`? You're right that it's only set in the activation handler... that's the only place *any* of your code is running as far as I know from what you've shared. If you have some other place that you plan on using that value, where is that? Why not use the default there?

Comment: I don't actually want to use $tab.text() at all, just that it is there as part of the original code and it seemed a usable method to trigger the show/hide of various <td>
The plugin that is in use is this one
http://webthemez.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html#parentHorizontalTab3
I did consider using the pseudo classes (aria-controls="tab_item-0", aria-controls="tab_item-1" etc) that are assigned to the tabs in the jquery file, a copy of which is viewable here http://zencart.hosting/js/ProductTabs.js  but I was even more at a loss in there.

Comment: I'm getting a little lost. Perhaps you can share your code so far and explain what you want it to do that it's not currently doing. E.g. "When you click on a tab, I want only the content related to that tab to be displayed." <-- Just a guess as to what you might be trying to do.

Comment: I'll update the bottom of the original question to explain what I have got now and what the issue is.